# How To Get Top Fans Data?

Tags: android, youtube-api

Is there any way to get my YouTube channel's top fans data? I heard there is a YouTube api but didnt find info about fans.

This is your channel's youtube fan page : https://www.youtube.com/audience?sf=engagement_score

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you want to achieve can be performed by using [Youtube Analytics and Reporting APIs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/). Specifically, [Channel reports](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/channel_reports#Filters). However, there is no functionality to return "Top Fans" per-se. However, you can use this API and develop a function that compares subscribers of your channels against how many videos they have liked, shared, favorited, added to playlists or any other logic that you want to implement. However, that will have to be done and defined by you on your end.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It sounds good. Can I get how many videos "Josh" liked in my channel?